# Required String parameter 'querycontent' is not present while sending multiple parameters Ajax stringify request with Jquery in Spring MVC Application

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

when press submit button, #dbresult will display value in select option and textarea.
error message in Console:

org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver logException
Warn: Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'querycontent' is not present]

query.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<title>Query DB</title>
</head>
<body>
    db:
    <select name="dbname" id="dbname">
        <option value="ibop_test">ibop_test</option>
        <option value="ibop">ibop</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <textarea class="boxsizingBorder" id="sqlstr"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button onclick="showresult()">submit</button>
    <div id="dbresult"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showresult() {
        document.getElementById("dbresult").innerHTML = "querying...";
        var dbname = document.getElementById('dbname').value;
        var sqlstr = document.getElementById('sqlstr').value;
        var querycontent = JSON.stringify({
            "dbname" : dbname,
            "sqlstr" : sqlstr
        });
        console.log(querycontent); //In Chrome's developer tools window, we will see the logs
        $
                .ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : 'showresult', 
                    contentType : 'application/json',
                    data : querycontent,
                    dataType : 'html',
                    success : function(msg) {
                        document.getElementById("dbresult").innerHTML = msg;
                    },
                    error : function() {
                        document.getElementById("dbresult").innerHTML = "querying failed!";
                    }
                })
    }
</script>
</html>
```

DBQueryController.java

```
@Controller
public class DBQueryController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/showresult", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String showResult(@RequestParam String querycontent){
        String message = "db query result content.</br>";
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using `@RequestParam` instead of `@RequestBody`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are sending data in body in your `AJAX` call, hence `@RequestParam` will not work. You needs to use `@RequestBody` instead like following:

```
@Controller
public class DBQueryController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/showresult", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String showResult(@RequestBody Map<String, String> querycontent){
        String message = "db query result content.</br>";
        return message;
    }
}
```

Or simply you can create a `POJO` class `DBQuery` like following and use it in controller.

```
public class DBQuery {
    private String dbname;
    private String sqlstr;
    // Getters and setters
}



 @Controller
    public class DBQueryController {
        @RequestMapping(value = "/showresult", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody String showResult(@RequestBody DBQuery querycontent){
            String message = "db query result content.</br>";
            return message;
        }
   }
```

Coming back to error, since you are not passing `querycontent` in request as parameter that's why it its throwing

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'querycontent' is not present]
```